# Switching colors on sprites issue

Tags: c#, 2d, unity-game-engine

So I have made a simple game with a couple key features.

A basic overview: You are a square. You must get from point A to point B. It's a platformer. (First game, don't hate).

Anyways, I decided to implement an interesting feature. There are only 2 possible colors. Black and white. If you are white, then the ground is black. If the ground is white, then you are black. The background is solid white. So basically you can choose to look at your player, or see where you are moving. You can switch back and forth with the Shift key.

Now, my problem is switching the levels color. The level is all 1 spite, with individually placed box colliders on the platforms. I am able to switch between white and black on the player, however the ground isn't switching colors no matter how many times I press it.

(The problem is not with timing, just getting the ground to also switch colors when shift is pressed.)

I have 2 separate scripts which are identical. The only difference between the one set on the ground, is that the boolean is swapped so you are never the same color as the ground. Here's my code. Can someone help me figure out why I can't get the ground to change but the player no problem?
Same is happening with the spikes (They're separate sprites)

```
private bool colorSet = true;

void Start () 
{

}


void Update () 
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.RightShift)) 
    {
        colorSet = !colorSet;
    }


    if (colorSet == true) 
    {
        gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer> ().color = Color.white;
        Debug.Log ("I should be white!");
    }

    else if (colorSet == false) 
    {
        gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer> ().color = Color.black;
        Debug.Log ("I should be black!");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have had cases where I have to do the following to get color changes to work on a sprite. It just adds the small piece .material to your code.

```
gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().material.color = Color.your_color_here;
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll give it a try once I'm back at my battle station. It's weird that it worked fine on the square but not the map? Perhaps its because of all the different collision boxes or something.

Comment: Where is the script attached? Is it attached to the game object containing the sprite?

Comment: Just drag and dropped after using the sprite editor. Only thing attached to them are box colliders, the actual sprites aren't parented to anything

Comment: could you post a screen shot of the gameobject in the hierarchy and the inspector?